# SSH password rejected on brand new install

Tags: ssh, software-installation

I installed the latest (as of today) Raspberry OS (no desktop, x64) on a headless RPi 3.

The installation went fine, I added the `ssh` file to start the SSH daemon and managed to connect to the service: `ssh pi@correctIp` prompts me for the fingerprint, then for the password.

According to the docs, it should be `raspberry` but it is rejected.

A verbose connection from a Window 10 shows an error (not sure if it is related):

```
PS C:\Users\yop> ssh pi@192.168.0.106 -v
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.106 [192.168.0.106] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.0.106:22 as 'pi'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Pdy/9HbtoxBJtu9DKxOjzjCMyq3apdki3n42aHfoyQs
debug1: Host '192.168.0.106' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: .\\YOP-AWS.pem RSA SHA256:gY1I0chf9zYNYvC+Ehsj1BBVNUKXDn8QJTYr8omlbqs agent
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\yop\\.ssh\\wojtek.swiatek.3ds.com.openssh RSA SHA256:mqynvkcmRmRYxvEmBDRPqS4cV293pXHD/kDNANknDew agent
debug1: Will attempt key: srv RSA SHA256:QYrUo5lqRVHW1vJ7Cp7cVqSnAWNoJlQIWMvIcHNHnKw agent
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: .\\YOP-AWS.pem RSA SHA256:gY1I0chf9zYNYvC+Ehsj1BBVNUKXDn8QJTYr8omlbqs agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: srv RSA SHA256:QYrUo5lqRVHW1vJ7Cp7cVqSnAWNoJlQIWMvIcHNHnKw agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\yop/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
pi@192.168.0.106's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
pi@192.168.0.106's password:
```

I tried with an AZERTY and a QWERTY keyboard (just in case).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from April 2022 there is [no more default username](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/).

According to the solutions provided in the link, I created a file `userconf.txt` in the boot partition of the SD card and put the line

```
wazaa:$2a$06$eGaS.lGIti3uadl/YcRJvuiiy8kJQHbJvNZVfAg2dJOgdxmTaezrC
```

The hash was generated via the [devgalan bcrypt](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/bcrypt-hash-generator) utility (this is an online service so you obviously must weight the security pros and cons of using it).

Comment: So many people are stumbling over this; it should probably be a *canonical question* (aka hypophora :)    Perhaps you could do this? Seems like a guaranteed vote-getter as all future questions will be closed as duplicates of the canonical question?

Comment: @Seamus  *Perhaps you could do this?* Sure, but what should I do exactly? (I do not care about the rep so that part does not matter if it can help others)

Comment: A *"canonical question"* is one that represents a Frequently-Asked-Question. Typically, one person writes up both the question, and the answer. When you click the `Ask Question` button in the URHC of the page, you'll see the standard layout for a question; you'll also see at the bottom, an option to `Answer your own question`. AKA "Share your knowledge". That's all there is to it. You can take the answer as far as you'd like: explain the problem, provide one or more alternative solutions, even script a solution that does everything that the RPi image ***used to do***.

Comment: @Seamus: ah ok, you mean to change the content of the question and adapt the answer. I can di that, sure. I thought that was a specific process to make a question canonical like in SO or Linux & Unix (where they use a specific tag for such questions)

Comment: There's really nothing *"bureaucratic"* about it. FWIW, here's a [Q&A on *meta* on the subject](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2068/do-we-need-a-canonical-question-about-cron-setup-on-the-pi) - the **topic** is different, but the process is the same. Note that the person who asked this question never quite got around to formulating his canonical question :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem. I copied the usual "raspberry" as password and imported it into. After that it worked and i changed it to german layout. Maybe try that. Care also about US and GB keyboard layout. It made difference for me

Comment: Thanks. I already tried to copy/paste. Also in WinSCP or Putty (as opposed to powershell)